# SSH tunnel to access the internet include DNS

Tags: ssh-tunneling

My setup is as follow:
The IT blocked access to use anydesk.
I have a linux machine (at home) that I access it over the internet.
The linux machine IP == 192.168.1.10
My router default gateway is == 192.168.1.1

I would like to ssh from the office to my home (using my public IP) and to open my browser to bypass the local restrictions to get anydesk running.

Comment: "The IT blocked access to use anydesk." They do not do this for fun or to annoy people, they do this for a reason. That may be risk or security related. Anyway, you will need some port forwarding on your router to your machine if you want it to work, so your local IP addresses are irrelevant.

Comment: Depending on corporate policy, you can be fired for doing this (and rightfully so).

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel has some ideas on this topic, but note that the address of your default gateway isn't `192.168.1.1` *from the perspective of the outside world*.